# vb.net Windows 10 not recognizing ActiveX libraries when Run as Administrator

Tags: windows-10, activex

We have an application which uses some ActiveX components and is compiled with "RequireAdministrator" level UAC settings.  In the vast majority of cases, everything works fine in Windows 10.  However, every once in a while, we face some Windows 10 stations where the application does not run and returns an error indicating that the ActiveX libraries are not properly registered.  On those same stations, other applications not requiring administrator level clearance and which use the very same ActiveX libs do run properly though.  Going into User Account Settings and simply setting the UAC to "Never notify" does not help.  Could it have something to do with User Account Control Group Policy settings and, if so, which one must be turned off?

Thanks!!!